# GAE datastore - best practice when there are more writes than reads

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to do some practicing with the GAE datastore to get a feeling about the queries and billings mechanisms.

I've read the Oreilly book about the GAE, and watched the Google videos about the datastore. My problem is that the best practice methods are usually concerning more reads than writes to the datastore.

I Built a super simple app:

- there are two webpages - one to
  choose links, and one view chosen
  links
- every user can choose to add url links to his "links feed"
- the user can choose as many links as he wants, whenever he wants.
- on a different webpage, I want to show the user the most recent 10 links he chose.
- every user has his own "links feed" webpage.
- on every "link" I want to save and show some metadata - for example: the url link itself; when it was chosen; how many times it appeared on the feed already; etc.

In this case, since the user can choose as many links he wants, whenever he wants, my app write to the datastore, much more than the number of reads (write - when the user chose another link; read - when the user opens the webpage to see his "links feed")

**Question 1:**
I can think of (at least) two options how to handle the data for this app:

*Option A:*
- maintain entity per user with the user details, registration, etc
- maintain another entity per user that holds his recent 10 chosen links, which will be rendered to the user's webpage after he asks for it

*Option B:*
- maintain entity per url link - which means all the urls of all users will be stored as the same object
- maintain entity per user details (same as in Option A), but add a reference to the user's urls in the big table of the urls

What will be the better method?

**Question 2:**
If I want to count the total numbers of urls chosen till today, or the daily amount of urls the user chose, or any other counting - should I use it with my SDK tools, or should I insert counters in the entities I described above? (I want to reduce the amount of datastore writes as much as I can)

**EDIT** (to answer @Elad's comment):
Assume I want to save only the 10 last urls per users. the rest of them I want to get rid of (so to not overpopulate my DB with unnecessary data).

**EDIT 2: after adding the code**
So I made the try with the following code (trying first Elad's method):

Here's my class:

```
class UserChannel(db.Model):
currentUser = db.UserProperty()
userCount = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
currentList = db.StringListProperty() #holds the last 20-30 urls
```

then I serialized the url & metadata into JSON strings, which the user POSTs from the first page.
here's how the POST is dealt:

```
def post(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:  
        logging messages for debugging
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        #self.response.out.write('<p>the user_id is: %s</p>' % user.user_id())            
        updating the new item that user adds
        current_user = UserChannel.get_by_key_name(user.nickname())
        dataJson = self.request.get('dataJson')
        #self.response.out.write('<p>the dataJson is: %s</p>' % dataJson) 
        current_user.currentPlaylist.append(dataJson)
        sizePlaylist= len(current_user.currentPlaylist)
        self.response.out.write('<p>size of currentplaylist is: %s</p>' % sizePlaylist)
        #whenever the list gets to 30 I cut it to be 20 long
        if sizePlaylist > 30:
            for i in range (0,9):
                current_user.currentPlaylist.pop(i)
        current_user.userCount +=1
        current_user.put()
        Updater().send_update(dataJson) 
    else:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        self.response.out.write('user_not_logged_in')
```

where Updater is my method for updating with Channel-API the webpage with the feed.

Now, it all works, I can see each user has a ListProperty with 20-30 links (when it hits 30, I cut it down to 20 with the pop()), but! the prices are quite high...
each POST like the one here takes ~200ms, 121 cpu_ms, cpm_usd= 0.003588. This is very expensive considering all I do is save a string to the list...
I think the problem might be that the entity gets big with the big ListProperty?

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you want to save all those URLs that the user chose for good, or just the 20 most recent URLs and throw away the older ones. Can you clarify please?

Comment: Elad you are right. It's two different cases. I updated my question with what you commented about.

Comment: great - that makes it more simple - see my answer below. BTW, out of sheer curiosity, what's the application? Why would I want to save some URLs but only see the last 10?

Comment: @Elad - thanks. 10 is just a number, it can be any number, but I'm thinking of a dynamic feed, like my facebook, only that I don't really need the data which is older than x days, since it's not relevant. Of course in the future I might want to save the user's feed history forever, but not right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're right to worry about lots of writes to GAE datastore - my own experience is that they're very expensive compared to reads. For instance, an app of mine that did nothing but insert records in a single model table reached exhausted the free quota with a few 10's of thousands of writes per day. So handling writes efficiently translates directly into your bottom line.

**First Question**

I wouldn't store links as separate entities. The datastore is not a RDBMS, so standard normalization practices do not necessarily apply. For each User entity, use a ListProperty to store the the most recent URLs along with their metadata (you can serialize everything into a string).

- This is efficient for writing since you only update a single record - there are no updates to all the link records whenever the user adds links. Keep in mind that to keep a rolling list (FIFO) with references URLs stored as separate models, every new URL means two write actions - an insert of the new URL, and a delete to remove the oldest one.
- It's also efficient for reading since a single read on the user record gives you all the data you need to render the User's feed.
- From a storage perspective, the total number of URLs in the world far exceeds your number of users (even if you become the next Facebook), and so does the variance of URLs chosen by your users, so it's likely that the mean URL will have a single user - no real gain in RDBMS-style normalization of the data.

Another optimization idea: if your users usually add several links in a short period you can try to write them in bulk rather than separately. Use memcache to store newly added user URLs, and the Task Queue to periodically write that transient data to the persistent datastore. I'm not sure what's the resource cost of using Tasks though - you'll have to check.
[Here's a good article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/memcache.html#transient) to read on the subject.

**Second Question**

Use counters. Just keep in mind that they aren't trivial in a distributed environment, so read up - there are many GAE articles, recipes and blog posts on the subject - just [google appengine counters](http://www.google.com/search?q=appengine+counters). Here too, using memcache should be a good option in order to reduce the total number datastore writes.

Comment: thanks @Elas! well, when you say "serialize everything into a string" do you mean doing it like - for example - the youtube url where many parameters are in the URL? lots of = & and ? to differentiate the different parameters?

Comment: Serializing everything to a string lets you avoid 2 writes but keep in mind that if you ever want to store any properties with a link in future e.g. the number of users sharing it, then you wont be able to search and sort on your properties, you will have to deserialize the list property elements to find the value of the property.

Comment: @Hamutsi The problem is that ListProperty can't store arbitrary objects, so if you want to store information in addition to the URL you'll need to serialize it somehow. URL params are an interesting idea. I was thinking more along the lines of JSON.

Comment: @Yasser you are right of course that storing blobs has the disadvantage of not allowing you to search them. The primary requirement right now however is a minimal number of writes. I believe that in general it is better to design to existing requirements, not potential future ones - those tend not to materialize. If they do, well, you cross the bridge when you get to it.

Comment: I meant a single ListProperty per User, with 20 elements in that list, where each contains the URL + metadata. The ListProperty element has to be serialized some way - ListProperty won't take arbitrary objects, and JSON is one serialization option.

Comment: Got ya, thanks :) (I'm still concerned about this method, that the entities will be too big, since URL+metadata can be ~400Bytes, 20 of these can make an entity with ListProperty that holds more than 10KB, but I am now going to try and see what happens)

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1**

Store Links as separate entities.  Also store an entity per user with a ListProperty having keys to the most recent 20 links.  As user chooses more links you just update the ListProperty of keys.  ListProperty maintains order so you dont need to worry about the chronological orders of links chosen as long as you follow a FIFO insertion order.

When you want to show the user's chosen links (page 2) you can do one get(keys) to fetch all the user's links in one call.

**Answer 2**

Definitely keep counters, as the number of entities grows, the complexity of counting records will continue to increase but with counters, the performance will remain the same.

Comment: Thanks Yasser. I was thinking about the ListProperty with the ref to keys, but here's my fear - now for every choice of link, there are two writes to the datastore: 1- adding the new link entity; 2-updating the List of most-updated links in the User entity. Assuming the users keep on choosing links, isn't it expensive?

Comment: If you make one entity per link and keep the user as reference property in it, then the cost of finding a user's most recent 20 links will keep on increasing as the number of users and links increases.  You can possibly decrease that cost by an additional timestamp in the link entity and have a composite index on user and timestamp to speed up the lookups.

Comment: Yasser, when you wrote "If you make one entity per link and keep the user as reference property in it" you meant instead of what you suggested before, or in addition (to the ListProperty with refs to keys)

Comment: My original suggestion stands i.e. you should keep a listproperty, but that requires two writes to the datastore as you pointed out. What i suggested in my comment was that if you want to avoid writes, then one way is to keep a reference property i.e. the standard way to do 1-m relationships in GAE.